# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection error in windows but same code is working in Linux in Svelte

Tags: svelte, nodejs-server

I am working in svelte and installed node modules using npm i. The same code is working in Linux. But, when I am trying to run the code on Windows I am getting the error shown in image.

command to run: npm run dev

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhYeT.jpg][1]

[1]:

Comment: Do you use the same nodejs version on Linux and Windows?

Comment: Found this, might be the same issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17405

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much. First, it's just a warning, second, it's on the packager (rollup) and not on your application code. Check the node versions on both system. The one on windows is probably newer and that's why it reports that.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. I have node version 13 and I downgraded it to 12.